# Extract pandas dataframe column names from query string

Tags: python, pandas, string, extract

I have a dataset with a lot of fields, so I don't want to load all of it into a `pd.DataFrame`, but just the basic ones.

Sometimes, I would like to do some filtering upon loading and I would like to apply the filter via the `query` or `eval` methods, which means that I need a query string in the form of, i.e. `"PROBABILITY > 10 and DISTANCE <= 50"`, but these columns need to be loaded in the dataframe.

Is is possible to extract the column names from the query string in order to load them from the dataset?

I know some magic using `regex` is possible, but I'm sure that it would break sooner or later, as the conditions get complicated.

So, I'm asking if there is a native `pandas` way to extract the column names from the query string.

Comment: where is the data coming from, SQL?

Comment: from a parquet dataset

Comment: so you want to get the column names from your `HIVE` query?

Comment: Actually, at the point when I make the `df.query` call, everything is already in the dataframe format. The procedure is such that I initiate a pyarrow dataset from the parquet on disk. On the pyarrow dataset I can call the `to_table(columns=my_columns)` and then `to_pandas()`, but I already need to know what `my_columns` are from the query string which is provided from the outside, which will then be applied on the dataframe object, which should already contain the specific columns needed for the query to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use when you load your dataframe the term use cols I use it when I load a csv I dont know that is possible when you use a SQL or other format.

Columns_to use=['Column1','Column3']
pd.read_csv(use_cols=Columns_to_use,...)

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, this is in fact my current solution, but I wanted to know if I could infer teh columns to use from the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and unfortunately can't find any official support for this. [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) uses [`eval()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) under the hood, which does a lot of nontrivial things such as reading in global/local variables, using different engines, etc.

I looked at the [source code where queries are parsed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/af83376640ec7d86cb3166d0e01052dc6648bfdf/pandas/core/computation/eval.py#LL336C14-L336C14) and came up with a hacky solution. Caveats:

1. It can't differentiate between column names and other available variables, but you can do that elsewhere in your code.
2. It uses regex, but only on a single variable name from an error message, which is more robust than a regex on the entire query string.
3. It uses `pandas.core` which is [considered private and unstable](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/af83376640ec7d86cb3166d0e01052dc6648bfdf/doc/source/reference/index.rst?plain=1#L33).

Example usage:

```py
extract_variables("PROBABILITY > 10 and DISTANCE <= 50")
# ['PROBABILITY', 'DISTANCE']
```

Code for `extract_variables()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

def extract_variables(query: str):
    # Track variables in a dictionary to be used as a dictionary of globals.
    variables = {}

    while True:
        try:
            # Try creating a Expr object with the query string and dictionary of globals.
            # This will raise an error as long as the dictionary of globals is incomplete.
            env = pd.core.computation.scope.ensure_scope(level=0, global_dict=variables)
            pd.core.computation.eval.Expr(query, env=env)

            # Exit the loop when evaluation is successful.
            break
        except pd.errors.UndefinedVariableError as e:
            # This relies on the format defined here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/965ceca9fd796940050d6fc817707bba1c4f9bff/pandas/errors/__init__.py#L401
            name = re.findall("name '(.+?)' is not defined", str(e))[0]

            # Add the name to the globals dictionary with a dummy value.
            variables[name] = None

    return list(variables.keys())
```